# DSpace 4.1: Files cannot be uploaded

Tags: dspace

I'm trying to upload files into my DSpace 4.1 repository. However, an error occurres when I press the Upload button. It throws me: `java.io.ioException: No existe el archivo o el directorio` which in English is: `java.io.ioException: No such file or directory`

What I did before was installing DSpace, creating the communities and collections, creating and deploying my own theme and translating some parts to Spanish (since DSpace didn't auto-translated some parts of the repository).

I'm using a user named `dspace`, which is the one I used to installed Tomcat and it's the owner of the `[dspace]` directory.

I'm using DSpace 4.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.

NOTE: Both `assetstore` and `upload` directories do exist, are owned by the `dspace` user, who also has read & write permissions to them; but still, I can't upload files to my repository. Could it be something about the configuration of the collection? Or something about Catalina and Tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you still need an answer for this but you should try changing the owner of [dspace]/assetstore to tomcat (just for a quick test) and then try uploading a file. I had the exact same error and this fixed it, meaning that the problem was that tomcat wasn't installed as the dspace user. From here, you can take the appropriate measures to change permissions to solve the issue for the production environment.

Comment: Thanks Christian, but it didn't worked. Probably I have to re-install it so it's linked to `tomcat` instead of `dspace`.

Comment: Thanks once again, Christian. As I said, it didn't worked with `tomcat` user, but because I understood that I had to create one. But since you said it worked for you in a similar problem, I dug a bit and I realised that the `tomcat` user was the one given by Tomcat (`tomcat7:tomcat7`). I changed it and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: glad it worked, i meant to write 'tomcat user' because I wasn't sure which version of tomcat you were using but I also used tomcat7 user. Now that you are sure about this, you should check with your server admins because there might be security implications about leaving the owner as tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user "dspace" is the owner of the "assetstore.dir" configured in dspace.cfg.

Comment: It seems that there's no assetstore.dir owner. How do I set one?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you told me. User `dspace` is in fact owner of `assetstore`. Still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are stored in **upload.temp.dir** as specified in your dspace.cfg file. Check if that directory exists and that user 'dspace' has read & write permissions to it.

Comment: As same as with the `asseststore` directory, user `dspace` owns and has read & write permissions to the `upload` directory. But the problem remains.